# What's the Mozilla Tamarin status?

Tags: virtual-machine, mozilla, avm2

Wikipedia claims Tamarin under Mozilla is active, but it's not listed under mozilla labs projects at all and it seems all docs from MDN are in 'obsolete' section. Is the project still supported?

Answer (score 1):

Seems Tamarin is no longer active. I talked to some guys handling MDN pages and they moved all related pages to obsolete sections claiming that neither Tamarin nor any of related components is actively used anywhere.